# Increasing pulse length

Tags: frequency

I have a signal that goes low for about 0.2μs or faster and i want to create an active low pulse about 1.8μs every time the input pulse goes low. How could i do that?

I want it to drive the !WAIT pin of a cpu to give time on a slow peripheral to latch the input.

Also, it would help if the output didn't pull high before and after the pulse so i can use multiple circuits tuned for different peripherals.

Also, every component needs to be through hole

Comment: 74121 comes to mind, if you can find them anymore. I think their minimum input width is \$50\:\text{ns}\$ or so. So good enough for this use.

Comment: 0.2 µs *does* imply through-hole might be a bad, bad restriction. Have you taken into account the inductance and stray capacitance of pins? I hope you're not doing this on breadboard...

Comment: @MarcusMüller i have not taken into account the capacitance or inductance, there are wires all over the place so i'm just testing my limits ( https://imgur.com/a/14cyneR ).Anyway, the solution won't work unfortunately because when the output goes low the CPU stops so the input freezes on low and the system locks up.

Comment: I might use something like that https://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/04191.png but with active low signals. The not gate delay might even be enough for the slow peripheral to latch the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f41LEnm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: would a 74hcu04 work as well instead of the 74hc14 because i already have one on the board for the clock

Comment: I would think so, considering the timing

Comment: Not as well, but it will work. HC14 is schmitt trigger. Period will be longer. HC14 definitely preferred for long periods. 1us hc04 prob OK

Answer (score 0):

try a 74hct174 or a 74hc112 configured as the equivalent of a 555 timer one shot.

http://www.discovercircuits.com/DJ-Circuits/oneshots.htm

Comment: whould it be fast enough?

Comment: oops sorry I didn't relize his small timing. 74hc112 or 74hct174 configued as a one shot would be suited for that instead of 555